# reading an excel file, checking that format and values are correct

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I am doing a test here on reading an excel file, checking the format and values of the cells.

I need to check these things specifically:

- colA has integers
- colB has integers formatted as 0001, 0012 and so forth
- colD should have an integer if ColC has an 1
- colE should have a 4 digit clock like 0300

Whats the correct approach here?

Now Im making functions for checking Integers like:

```
Int(sheet.Cells(row, col)) = sheet.Cells(row, col)
```

This will check the integer values, but whats the best way of checking all the other things?
I've heard about a validator object I can use.

Anyone have any tricks on this subject?

Comment: FOR A, D, E data validation should work (data tab, data validation).  for B input mask with data validation.  it would prevent the data from being put in wrong in the first place.  but if you can't do that then VBA will be required.

Comment: Lets say I don't have control over the input file. I read it with vba and check for faults, any way of using the automatic validator in vba?

Comment: Do you want to check a new excel file at edit-time (from within excel), or do you have to check a whole lot of already existing excel files (e.g. to import / bulk-load them into a database)? Does it have to be VBA?

Comment: Then no, I have no tricks. you'd have to for each row in sheet for each  column in sheet if row column is a int validation else b int and format validation if d and c =1 then int validation if 3 int and format validation.  the real question is how are you wantoing to record the errors?  say column A has text.  what then?

Comment: Someone sends me the files on email. If they are OK I add the info (minus the header) to a historical sheet.. The Historical sheet is made of all the small files appended..

Comment: add the data validation to the historical sheet, when you copy/paste data validation triggers will fire preventing the paste... No... nm they won't just tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code validates the ActiveSheet per your rules. For Column B, I understood you to mean that the value is actually text, not that the cell is formatted with leading zeros.

```
Sub Validate()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lNumRows As Long
    Dim bRowValid As Boolean
    Dim bSheetValid As Boolean

    With ActiveSheet
        bSheetValid = True    ' initial assumption is sheet is valid
        lNumRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For lRow = 2 To lNumRows
            bRowValid = IsInteger(.Cells(lRow, 1).Value)
            bRowValid = bRowValid And IsFormatted(.Cells(lRow, 2).Value)
            If .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = 1 Then
                bRowValid = bRowValid And IsInteger(.Cells(lRow, 4).Value)
            End If
            bRowValid = bRowValid And IsTime(.Cells(lRow, 5).Value)
            bSheetValid = bSheetValid And bRowValid
            If Not bRowValid Then
                ' do something here if you want to flag this row
            End If
        Next lRow
    End With

    If bSheetValid Then
        ' copy data to historical sheet
    End If
End Sub
Function IsInteger(vValue As Variant) As Boolean
    If VarType(vValue) = vbDouble Then
        IsInteger = (Fix(vValue) = vValue)
    Else
        IsInteger = False
    End If
End Function
Function IsFormatted(vValue As Variant) As Boolean
    If VarType(vValue) = vbString Or VarType(vValue) = vbDouble Then
        IsFormatted = vValue Like "[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
    Else
        IsFormatted = False
    End If
End Function
Function IsTime(vValue As Variant) As Boolean
    If IsFormatted(vValue) Then
       IsTime = IsDate(Left$(vValue, 2) & ":" & Right$(vValue, 2))
    Else
        IsTime = False
    End If
End Function
```

Here are some alterations you might want to consider:

- Change the `For...Loop` to a `Do...Loop` so that you can stop as soon as invalid data is found. Do this if you don't care to know which rows were invalid.
- Add highlighting for invalid data if you want to see the errors. Do this in the `If Not bRowValid...` block.
- Change `Sub Validate` to a function that takes the worksheet as a parameter and returns a `boolean`. IOW, separate the validation from the code that copies data to the historical sheet.

Comment: It's actually an integer formatted with leading zeroes, but your answer is amazing and I can use most of it in my code. Thank you for using your time to look at my problem and solving it :)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to parse an external file, here is a little perl script (untested from the top off my head).

```
use Regexp::Common;
use Test::More;
#use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel; if using excel <=2003

use Spreadsheet::XLSX;


my $excel = Spreadsheet::XLSX -> new ('test.xlsx');

foreach my $sheet (@{$excel -> {Worksheet}}) {


    printf("Sheet: %s\n", $sheet->{Name});

    $sheet -> {MaxRow} ||= $sheet -> {MinRow};

     foreach my $row ($sheet -> {MinRow} .. $sheet -> {MaxRow}) {

            $sheet -> {MaxCol} ||= $sheet -> {MinCol};

            foreach my $col ($sheet -> {MinCol} ..  $sheet -> {MaxCol}) {

                    my $cell = $sheet -> {Cells} [$row] [$col];

                    if ($cell) {
                     if ($col == 0){ #colA
                         $cell =~ qr/$RE{num}{int}/ or fail "Value '$cell' in cell($row, $col) is not an int";
                     }
                     if ($col == 1){ #colB


                         int($cell) or fail "Value '$cell' in cell($row, $col) cannot be parsed to an int";
                         $cell =~ /\d{4}/ or fail "Value '$cell' in cell($row, $col) does not consist of 4 digits"; # must they be consecutive?


                     }
                     if ($col == 3){ #D
                          my  $cellC = $sheet -> {Cells} [$row] [$col - 1]
                          if ($cellC == 1){
                             $cell =~ qr/$RE{num}{int}/ or fail "Value '$cell' in cell($row, $col) is not an int although ColC is 1 ";
                          } 

                     }
                     # one more test for colE
                    }

            }
    }
}
done_testing();
```

For the  colE test, you have to find your own patterns / regular expressions, but that should not be too difficult. 
For checking time values in perl, see here:
[http://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::time](http://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp%3a%3aCommon%3a%3atime)
I have not used this module, though.

See also [http://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common](http://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp%3a%3aCommon)

In VBA you have to load a Microsoft Regular Expression type library (which comes pre-installed on windows). The whole VBA code will be similar to my pseudocode above, but more verbose.

Comment: An unprompted perl script! What a peculiar suggestion!

Comment: Never tried perl but it looks like it's doing what I intended. But what I was hoping for was some of the syntaxes and functions in excel to help me going. Still you get an upvote :) thank you

Comment: @jean-françois-corbett: Actually, I combined two templates: The outer loop came from the "Synopsis" section of the perldoc for Spreadsheet::XLSX. The tests inside the "if" blocks came from the perldoc of Regexp::Common. I only wrote the regexes (which can be simplified even further). Besides, I've done something similar (reading and writing excel files in perl) for my own day job.